MS SQL Server Availability group listener port setup
There are a lot of useful, similar questions on this topic, as well as this part of the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/availability-group-listener-overview?view=sql-server-ver15#SelectListenerPort):

You can also designate a non-standard availability group listener port. However, you also need to explicitly use the target port in your application connection string when connecting to a listener. You also need to open permission on the firewall for this port.
You can connect to the listener using the name and port (if not 1433). The port can be either the listener port or the underlying SQL Server port that it's configured to listen on.

In this documentation there were practical examples of connection strings if you have 2 instances with port number 50254 and listener has port number 50123. It is shown that you can use either port number in your connection string.
So my question is if you use a default 1433 port for SQL instances and lets say some random port 50123, can you utilize the AG listener functionality which allows to login to the AG without specifying port - because the connection string will allow blank port number, since the instances are running on the default port? And is this considered an OK thing to do and are there any drawbacks of using this kind of approach?.
Edit:
And one more thing, instance I am running Availability group from is a named instance. And when I connect to the listener via listener\NamedInstanceName it doesn't need port number to successfully connect even though the port of both instances and listener is a non default port 50123. Is this a possible safe way to bypass the need of port in the connection string as well?


In this documentation there were practical examples of connection strings if you have 2 instances with port number 50254 and listener has port number 50123. It is shown that you can use either port number in your connection string.

The documentation is arguably incorrect as it assumes no changes to the SQL Server network configuration. The example in the documentation only works because by default SQL Server is set to listen on any IP. Should you configure this otherwise, the example of changing port numbers will no longer work.

So my question is if you use a default 1433 port for SQL instances and lets say some random port 50123, can you utilize the AG listener functionality which allows to login to the AG without specifying port - because the connection string will allow blank port number, since the instances are running on the default port? And is this considered an OK thing to do and are there any drawbacks of using this kind of approach?.

Assuming you have it listening on all IPs, it should work. I would not rely on this behavior and I don't see any reason to use a different port than 1433, unless you're using a distributed network name in which case you're going to need to look at your networking and SQL infrastructure very carefully before choosing the configuration.

And one more thing, instance I am running Availability group from is a named instance. And when I connect to the listener via listener\NamedInstanceName it doesn't need port number to successfully connect even though the port of both instances and listener is a non default port 50123. Is this a possible safe way to bypass the need of port in the connection string as well?

This should not work when connecting remotely as the listener does not participate in named instance port lookups via SQL Browser but it most likely will work locally on the server for various reasons, depending on the server setup. Doing this can actually connect you to the wrong instance, should there be multiples or other instances which resolve in a multi-subnet scenario.
You need to always use the port number when working with availability groups and listeners that aren't listening on 1433.
